# Odoo: Change dynamical the widget of a field

Tags: xml, odoo, odoo-13

my odoo application has many widgets defined for text fields. I created a field that allowed me to select the widget type. The XML used for this task was:

```
<field name="text" widget="html" attrs="{'invisible':[('type','!=','html')]}">
<field name="text" widget="markdown" attrs="{'invisible':[('type','!=','markdown')]}">
<field name="text" widget="json" attrs="{'invisible':[('type','!=','json')]}">
```

However, the field just render the last widget. I solved it by creating multiple fields of text (textjson,textmarkdown,texthtml). Now the code looks like this:

```
<field name="texthtml" widget="html" attrs="{'invisible':[('type','!=','html')]}">
<field name="textmarkdown" widget="markdown" attrs="{'invisible':[('type','!=','markdown')]}">
<field name="textjson" widget="json" attrs="{'invisible':[('type','!=','json')]}">
```

Do you know if there is a solution to dynamic change a widget from an element?

Answer (score 0):

Save types in separate `selection` field and apply it as widget by xpath the field `t-if="condition">` on based of that value the widget the text field attribute will assign.